# android - Accelerations work only in debug

Tags: android, accelerometer, acceleration

I have an app that records the phone's accelerations and saves them to a file.
When I check the app in debug mode on my phone, everything works great.
When I take the apk file and install it one the phone, the app dose'nt saves any accelerations?

Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but my tarot cards and crastal globe  are out of service today. You will have to provide more information ( logcat output,  some source code ) to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
When I debugged my code (service) I used `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` so I can debug the code. 
It seems that this line blocks the code after it while in release mode.
I removed the line and the problem solved.